# I need to remove all whitespaces from the input string and copy the new string to the other string in the deblank function. I am getting zsh bus error

Tags: c, c-strings, function-definition, removing-whitespace, bus-error

When I try to run this code it successfully asks me for a string and assigns it to the inpstr. When I call the deblank function i get "zsh bus error" Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    //Problem 1 Code
    //Declare a string and assign user input to it with fgets and chomp it

    char inpstr[20];
    char outstr[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(inpstr, 20, stdin);
    chomp(inpstr);

    //Call deblank to assign the copied string without whitespace to outstr
    deblank(inpstr, outstr);

    return 0;
}

void chomp(char word [])
{
    if(word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

void deblank(char *inpstr, char *outstr)
{
    //First we find the length of the string not including the null
    int length = strlen(inpstr);
    
    //declare a counting variable
    int o;

    //For loop to check each letter
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(inpstr[i] != ' ')
        {
            outstr[o] = inpstr[i];
            o++;
        }
    }
    
}
```

I have tried a few different things to maybe redefine the pointers, but nothing changed. Either got a compiling error or another zsh bus error. I have deleted code up to the `int length = strlen(inpstr)` and tested it and it runs correctly. I believe the error begins with the for loop in the `deblank` function. All the function prototypes were typed above the main function and libraries were also included.

Comment: The variable o is not initialized.

Comment: o is not initialized? It seems like it is initialized in the deblank function before the for loop

Comment: @Criticizze It's declared but not initialized. `int o = 0;` would initialize it.

Comment: @Criticizze I have not found where the variable o is initialized.:)

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

First of all the variable `o` was not initialized.

```
int o;
```

So using it as an index

```
outstr[o] = inpstr[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Another problem is that the array `outstr` will not contain a string because you forgot to append the terminating zero character '\0' to the stored sequence of characters in the array.

The function `deblank` could be defined the following way. Pay attention to that you should also remove tab characters `'\t'`. And using within the function the function `strlen` is inefficient. The function can be more simpler without declaring additional variables.

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

void deblank( const char *inpstr, char *outstr )
{
    do
    {
        if ( !isblank( ( unsigned char )*inpstr ) )
        {
            *outstr++ =  *inpstr;
        }
    } while ( *inpstr++ );
}
```

If you want to remove only the space character `' '` then the header `<ctype.h>` is not needed and the if statement within the function will look as

```
        if ( *inpstr != ' ' )
```

And at last the function `chomp`

```
void chomp(char word [])
{
    if(word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\n')
    {
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
    }
}
```

also can invoke undefined behavior if an empty string will be passed to it because the expression `strlen(word) - 1` will produce a big positive number.

Instead of using your manually written function you could just write in main

```
inpstr[ strcspn( inpstr, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: I wonder why they're getting bus error instead of segmentation violation. Bus error usually comes from using accessing data with incorrect alignment, but that can't happen with `char`.

Comment: @Barmar I am sorry, I can say nothing about that.

Answer (score 0):

- Initialize o
- Put \0 on end of outstr
- Use while with extra conditions to remove all \n, ' ' at the end
- Added includes and forwards to make it compile

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Add forwards
void chomp(char word []);
void deblank(char *inpstr, char *outstr);

int main()
{
    //Problem 1 Code
    //Declare a string and assign user input to it with fgets and chomp it

    char inpstr[20];
    char outstr[20];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(inpstr, 20, stdin);
    chomp(inpstr);

    //Call deblank to assign the copied string without whitespace to outstr
    deblank(inpstr, outstr);

    printf("The outstr: (%s)\n", outstr);
    return 0;
}

void chomp(char word [])
{
    // remove all  \n or ' '
    // there should be some length
    while(strlen(word) > 0 && (word[strlen(word) - 1] == '\n' ||  word[strlen(word) - 1] == ' ' ) )
    {
        word[strlen(word) - 1] = '\0';
    }
}

void deblank(char *inpstr, char *outstr)
{
    //First we find the length of the string not including the null
    int length = strlen(inpstr);

    //declare a counting variable
    int o=0;  // initialize it !!!

    //For loop to check each letter
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(inpstr[i] != ' ')
        {
            outstr[o] = inpstr[i];
            o++;
        }
    }
    outstr[o]='\0';  // end the contructed with \0

}
```

Good Luck